# Keyboard doesn't show when EditText is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard, android-edittext

I'm having a problem with the softkeyboard not showing when i click on a EditText.

The activity goes like this.
1. Activity starts
2. Dialog box opens with a custom keyboard
3. And then I try to click on an empty EditText field to put in data, but nothing happens. The field get focus, but keyboard doesn't show up.

I haven't done anything funky with disabling keyboard..

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `AVD manager` add a hardware property `Keyboard support` and set it to `false`.

That should disable the shown keyboard, and show the virtual one.